# How to update a state variable correctly using onClick in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created two tabs that when clicked need to show a different set of products and a different set of filters for each selection. My problem is that when I click either tab and call setOptions within changeTab, I need to click each tab twice before it will update 'options', 'options' needs to contain each filter.

Obviously calling setOptions within the click handler is not correct but I can't figure out where or how to correctly update 'options'. Help greatly appreciated.

In the console logs below 'dedupedOptions' updates correctly on click

```
function filterProducts() {

  const [categoryType, setCategory] = useState("Canine");
  const [activeTabIndex, setActiveTabIndex] = useState(0);
  const {
    productData: {
      products: { products }
    }
  } = useContext(AppContext);

  const productsByCategory = products
    .filter((product) => {
      const { tags } = product;
      return !!tags.find((tag) => tag.includes(categoryType));
    })
    .map((product) => ({
      ...product,
      category: product.tags
        .find((tag) => tag.includes("category:"))
        .split(":")[1]
    }));

  let dedupedOptions = [];

  productsByCategory.forEach((product) => {
    const { tags } = product;
    tags.forEach((tag) => {
      const parts = tag.split(":");
      const key = parts[0];
      const value = parts[1] || null;
      const validTag = tagKeysToDisplay.find(
        (tagKeyToDisplay) => tagKeyToDisplay === key
      );
      if (
        validTag &&
        !dedupedOptions.find((dedupedOption) => dedupedOption.value === value)
      ) {
        dedupedOptions = [
          ...dedupedOptions,
          {
            label: titleCase(value),
            value,
            selected: false
          }
        ];
      }
    });
  });

  const [options, setOptions] = useState(dedupedOptions);
  console.log(dedupedOptions);
  console.log(options);

  const changeTab = (index, category) => {
    setCategory(category);
    setActiveTabIndex(index);
    setOptions(dedupedOptions);
  };

  const setFilter = useCallback(
    (selectedOption) => {
      const optionIsActive = options.find(
        (option) => option.value === selectedOption.value
      )?.selected;
      let newOptions = [];
      newOptions = [
        ...options.map((option) => {
          if (option.value === selectedOption.value) {
            return {
              ...option,
              selected: !optionIsActive
            };
          }
          return option;
        })
      ];
      setOptions(newOptions);
    },
    [options]
  );
}
```

And the two elements set up as tabs to handle the click events. These are rendered within the same filterProducts function.

```
      <div className="filter-products__tabs">
        <div
          className={`filter-products__tab
          ${activeTabIndex === 0 ? "is-active" : ""}`}
          onClick={changeTab.bind(this, 0, "Canine")}
        >
          <span>DOG</span>
        </div>
        <div
          className={`filter-products__tab
          ${activeTabIndex === 1 ? "is-active" : ""}`}
          onClick={changeTab.bind(this, 1, "Feline")}
        >
          <span>CAT</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: It's better if you can reproduce that in https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Seems whatever `dedupedOptions` is has a dependency on the `categoryType` state. I think much of your logic compuing `dedupdedOptions` could be moved into a `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced your question by some changes in variable declarations in state.
**be careful to declare variables in state and do the updates by listening the variable changes inside the useEffect**.

here is the working code:\

https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-http-e264i?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useContext, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [categoryType, setCategory] = useState("Canine");
  const [activeTabIndex, setActiveTabIndex] = useState(0);
  const [productsByCategory, setProductsByCategory] = useState([]);
  const [dedupedOptions, setDedupedOptions] = useState([]);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(dedupedOptions);

  const products = [
    { tags: ["category:Feline"], name: "one" },
    { tags: ["category:Canine"], name: "two" }
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const productsByCategory = products
      .filter((product) => {
        const { tags } = product;
        return !!tags.find((tag) => tag.includes(categoryType));
      })
      .map((product) => ({
        ...product,
        category: product.tags
          .find((tag) => tag.includes("category:"))
          .split(":")[1]
      }));
    setProductsByCategory(productsByCategory);
  }, [categoryType]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let tmp_dedupedOptions = [];
    const tagKeysToDisplay = ["category"];
    productsByCategory.forEach((product) => {
      const { tags } = product;
      tags.forEach((tag) => {
        const parts = tag.split(":");
        const key = parts[0];
        const value = parts[1] || null;
        const validTag = tagKeysToDisplay.find(
          (tagKeyToDisplay) => tagKeyToDisplay === key
        );

        if (
          validTag &&
          !tmp_dedupedOptions.find(
            (dedupedOption) => dedupedOption.value === value
          )
        ) {
          tmp_dedupedOptions = [
            ...tmp_dedupedOptions,
            {
              label: value,
              value,
              selected: false
            }
          ];
        }
      });
    });
    setDedupedOptions(tmp_dedupedOptions);
    setOptions(tmp_dedupedOptions);
  }, [productsByCategory]);

  console.log("options: ", options);

  const changeTab = (index, category) => {
    setCategory(category);
    setActiveTabIndex(index);
  };

  const setFilter = useCallback(
    (selectedOption) => {
      const optionIsActive = options.find(
        (option) => option.value === selectedOption.value
      )?.selected;
      let newOptions = [];
      newOptions = [
        ...options.map((option) => {
          if (option.value === selectedOption.value) {
            return {
              ...option,
              selected: !optionIsActive
            };
          }
          return option;
        })
      ];
      setOptions(newOptions);
    },
    [options]
  );
  // }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="filter-products__tabs">
        <div
          className={`filter-products__tab
          ${activeTabIndex === 0 ? "is-active" : ""}`}
          onClick={changeTab.bind(this, 0, "Canine")}
        >
          <span>DOG</span>
        </div>
        <div
          className={`filter-products__tab
          ${activeTabIndex === 1 ? "is-active" : ""}`}
          onClick={changeTab.bind(this, 1, "Feline")}
        >
          <span>CAT</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```